# How do I load dataframes with columns having lists of equal length as tensorflow inputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataframe with feature data and label data, each as separate columns that contain lists of floats, like so:

```
ts = pd.DataFrame()
ts['features'] = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [3.0, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0]]
ts['labels'] = [[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]
```

I am trying to train a model with these features and labels, but I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).]
```

I thought maybe I could do:

```
x_train = np.asarray(ts.features)
y_train = np.asarray(ts.labels)
```

but I get the same error. I keep looking over tutorials and stuff as I feel like handling simple 2d arrays of floats as inputs and targets would surely be possible out of the box, but I must be missing something. For what it is worth, I'm pretty sick today but really want to get this done and I have wasted a few hours already.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What's the line you get the error *ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).]*?

Comment: the error occurred when I tried to pass the data in to model.fit(). ultimately just went with the approach I mention below to turn the single column DF with a list of floats into multi-column with 1 float per column.

Comment: So you call it like `model.fit(ts['features'], ts['labels'])`?

Comment: yes, sorry. like that

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

```
x_array = pd.DataFrame(ts.features.to_list())
y_array = pd.DataFrame(ts.labels.to_list())
```

to create a new DF with a column for every value that was in the lists of each row and then passing the dataframes into the network and it is working. using `np.asarray(ts.labels.to_list())` worked as well.